# Escape $ dollar sign in macro_rules

Tags: rust, rust-macros

How can I escape a dollar sign for a macro like this?

```
macro_rules! test {
    ($ $name:ident) => {
        println!(stringify!($name));
    };
}

fn main() {
    test!($abc);
}
```

I want to get `abc`. I've tried using `$$` and a bunch of possible ways to escape it but I can't find anything. All I can find on this online is to use `$$` to escape meta variables and produces an error. Can I use the literal type somehow?

Here is what I have tried:
`$$`
`\$`
`_$`
`$_$`
`$:literal`
`$$:literal`

Comment: Does a backslash before it work?

Comment: @Samathingamajig, Nope... I wish.

Comment: `macro_rules!` might have `$` as a reserved character, you might have to write a custom macro from scratch if you want to use a `$` literal

Comment: You can capture it as `tt`, but this does not enforce a dollar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per The Rust Reference,

> The character $ cannot be matched or transcribed literally.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#transcribing